# Can I make a user's home directory be /var/www/html for vsftp?

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 web server. It only hosts one site using Nginx. I want to keep things very simple, and store the index.html file and the whole website in `/var/www/html`.

I need to be able to FTP files into `/var/www/html`. I have installed vsftp. I've created a user with the `useradd` command, which I'll call `exampleuser`. I then used this command:

```
sudo usermod -d /var/www/html exampleuser
```

... thinking that this would make the home directory of `exampleuser` to be the default directory when I log in by FTP.

However, when I attempt to log in by FTP, I get a "login error". I've checked and double checked my username and password and I'm certain they're correct, so I'm guessing it's a permissions issue (also because my experience is that most of the time in Linux when things don't work as hoped it's because of permissions). Though it's possible it could be a vsftpd configurations issue.

I think I've set the `html` directory in `/var/www` to have the right access:

```
/var/www$ ls -la
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 Nov 10 06:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root          root          4096 Nov 10 06:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 exampleuser exampleuser 4096 Nov 10 08:04 html
```

What do I need to do so that I can ftp to `/var/www/html`?

Comment: Not a security expert but why not have sudo rm /var/www and then have sampleuser create /var/www and /var/www/html? Also does the directory have to be in /var which is a system folder?

Comment: What is the log in error ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, my client says "Login failed." The vsftp log says "FAIL LOGIN: Client".

Comment: What error is in your logs ? Simply stating it is not working and guessing at the problem is not going to make much progress. See also https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions#Folder.2FDirectory_Permissions as your directories do not have proper permissions.

Comment: What is in /var/log messages and vsftp logs ? apparmor error ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen, thank you for responding. What permissions should the directory have? The link you provided explains what permissions are, but not specifically what this situation requires.

Comment: I am not sure it is a permissions problem. You can try making /var and /var/www rwx by your other user, although that has it's own security problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is a permission error take a look on this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-vsftpd-for-a-user-s-directory-on-ubuntu-16-04):

> FTP is generally more secure when users are restricted to a specific
>   directory.vsftpd accomplishes this with chroot jails. When chroot is
>   enabled for local users, they are restricted to their home directory
>   by default. However, because of the way vsftpd secures the directory,
>   it must not be writable by the user. This is fine for a new user who
>   should only connect via FTP, but an existing user may need to write to
>   their home folder if they also shell access.
>
> In this example, rather than removing write privileges from the home
>   directory, we're will create an ftp directory to serve as the chroot
>   and a writable files directory to hold the actual files.
>
> Create the ftp folder, set its ownership, and be sure to remove write
>   permissions with the following commands:

```
sudo mkdir /home/sammy/ftp
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /home/sammy/ftp
sudo chmod a-w /home/sammy/ftp
```

If you try to connect to the ftp and the user can write the folder then it wont connect, you need to add to the root folder the owner nobody:nogroup, so if you want to keep things simple just point your server to the folder where the user can write in your case:

```
sudo usermod -d /var/www exampleuser
```

This is because you want to write on HTML folder

```
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /var/www
sudo chmod a-w /var/www
```

Modify your server conf file and point to the new location which will be HTML this solution helps a lot if you really want to use Very Safe FTP